# Cannot load phpmodule because it cannot be found

Tags: php, apache, windows-server-2012-r2

I've spent hours trying to figure this out to no avail.

http://editrocket.com/articles/php_apache_windows.html

I followed that (and many other guides nearly identical). I'm running Apache 2.4.17 x64, and PHP 5.6.15 x64.

`C:\www\bin>httpd.exe
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 71 of C:/www/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load c:/php
/php5apache2_4.dll into server: The specified module could not be found.`

Of course, I have my path right. The file is most certainly there.

Comment: I assume you've downloaded the php build from windows.php.net. Did you install the necessary visual c runtime redistributables? That would currently be the [vc11 update 4 redistributables](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you install [xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html). It's a stack that includes apache, mysql, php, phpmyadmin etc.

Comment: I kept seeing references to that, but never looked into it. Sounds a lot easier, I'll give it a go.